# Open Revit BIM360 Model via command line

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, revit

Has anyone successfully opened a cloud model via the command line? I can open a non-cloud model by passing the file path, but I'm not sure how you would open something non-local.

Comment: which command line are you talking about? and can you give an example of the commands ran to get what you want?

Comment: In this case Windows CMD or Powershell you can do something like `revit.exe C:\Models\Model.rvt` and it will open the model, but I can't do that for BIM 360 models.

Comment: Have you solved this yet? Can you confirm that it works and share how you did? Thank you!

Comment: I haven't. I got pulled onto another project and haven't had a chance to work on it. I'll post back here if and when we go back to it.

Answer (score 1):

The Revit 2020 API introduced the possibility to open a cloud model hosted in BIM360, cf. [Open/Save/Modify cloud models on BIM 360](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2020-api.html#4.2.6.2) in [What's New in the Revit 2020 API](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2020-api.html#4.2.6.2).

Another aspect of this new functionality is discussed by The Building Coder on the  [`IOpenFromCloudCallback` and the `DefaultOpenFromCloudCallback` class](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/05/precast-api-and-cloud-open-callback.html#3).

You could use the new functionality in your own add-in implementing a handler for the [`ApplicationInitialized` event](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/f35ba9fc-0b6b-4284-60eb-91788761127c.htm) to open a cloud model by passing in information to it either via the command line or by other means, e.g., reading an input file specifying the cloud model path to open.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I pass path to BIM 360 project's local cache, Revit treats it like I open BIM 360 project itself:

```
# powershell

& "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2020\Revit.exe" ^
    "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit 2020\CollaborationCache\<id>\<some guid>\<another guid>.rvt
```

But apparently it seems to be working only if BIM 360 project had been opened at least once and therefore cache is present in given folder.